# No entity found for query exception even there is a row for that query

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I wrote simple program for login a user.I can get all results from table and it works correctly , but when I want to check if a user with name and password exists always throw no entity found for query exception and I know there is a row in table with that name and password.
this is my code :

```
public List<Person> getList(){
    return entityManager.createQuery("select entity from person entity").getResultList();
}
public Person logIn(String name,String password){
      String selectQuery = "select entity from person entity where name=:name and password=:password";
      Person person = (Person)entityManager.createQuery(selectQuery)
              .setParameter("name",name)
              .setParameter("password",password)
              .getSingleResult();

      System.out.println(person);
      return person;
}
```

this is my entity class for Person

```
@Entity(name = "person")
    @Table(name = "PERSON")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID",columnDefinition = "NUMBER")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "PERSON_SEQ",sequenceName = "PERSON_SEQ",allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO,generator = "PERSON_SEQ")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "NAME",columnDefinition = "NVARCHAR2(30)")
    @NotNull(errorCode = "Null",message = "Name can't be null")
    @NotEmpty(errorCode = "Empty",message = "Name can't be empty")

    private String name;

    @Column(name = "FAMILY",columnDefinition = "NVARCHAR2(30)")
    @NotNull(errorCode = "Null",message = "Family can't be null")
    @NotEmpty(errorCode = "Empty",message = "Family can't be empty")
    private String family;

    @Column(name = "Password",columnDefinition = "VARCHAR2(256)")
    @NotNull(errorCode = "Null",message = "Family can't be null")
    @NotEmpty(errorCode = "Empty",message = "Family can't be empty")
    private String password; /*setter and getter methods....*/
```

Answer (score 2):

The method `getSingleResult()` may throw `NonUniqueResultException`, if there are multiple rows. So unless you have unique constraints in your table this might occur in the future.

Also make sure to use the `try/catch` block to know if you have a result or not:

```
      String selectQuery = "select entity from person entity where name=:name and password=:password";
      Person person = null;

      try{
       person = (Person)entityManager.createQuery(selectQuery)
              .setParameter("name",name)
              .setParameter("password",password)
              .getSingleResult();
      }
      catch(NoResultException e){
        //TO-DO do something if query retrieves nothing
      }       

      System.out.println(person);
      return person;
```

If not you can always use the above method `getResultList()` and just call `get(0)` for the first result.

If you really think the query returns a row, check your sql statement again.

**EDIT :**

You could give it a try with a native query

```
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM PERSON where name = ?1 and password = ?2";

    Query q = em.createNativeQuery(selectQuery);
    q.setParameter(1, name);
    q.setParameter(2, password);

    person = (Person) q.getSingleResult();
```

Comment: I handle this exception in my controller.I have this problem for example there is record in table that name is saba and password is 1234 but I get no entity found when I use login method with these parameters

Comment: check the table name, check if the parameters's values are correct(debug). also shouldn't the query be like :`'select p from person p where p.name=:name and p.password=:password'` ?

Comment: I edit my query like yours and remove try catch to see complete log ,this exception happened : SQLGrammarException: ORA-00904: "ENTITY": invalid identifier

Comment: @sabasafavi can you post the table schema and entity class in your question ?

Comment: maybe you could try with a native query @sabasafavi , see above.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Person has to be camelcase as follows:

```
select entity from Person entity
```